# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

What Google Maven dependency could fix this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.read(HttpStorageRpc.java:487)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobReadChannel$1.call(BlobReadChannel.java:127)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobReadChannel$1.call(BlobReadChannel.java:124)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:94)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:54)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobReadChannel.read(BlobReadChannel.java:124)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
```

Code:

```
Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
if(blob.exists()) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You have multiple versions of Guava on your classpath. Figure out which of your dependencies depend on Guava, and make sure only one version remains.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your Google guava version is either too old (< 20.0) or mismatched (multiple jars versions). Make sure you don't have several versions in your dependency tree.

Use

```
mvn dependency:tree | less
```

to look for the guava versions.

Comment: @Karl Richter, How and where should guava be defined in a Java app if we think there is a conflict between libraries? Can guava be overwritten as to only use one version?

Answer (score 15):

Please add following dependencies to your project's POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.6-jre</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I happened to include both

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>28.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

As it turns out, I cannot use both of these libraries. Removing google-collections fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try inserting a dependency containing a newer version of guava at the top of your dependencies in your pom.xml containing your project.

E.g.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>24.1.1-jre</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: thank you, that actually mattered, which I did not think it would :)

Answer (score 2):

For anybody encountering anything like this, i had the following pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20190722</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And commenting out the maven-shade plugin fixed it for me...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my Java/Kotlin application. When the app was ran via IntelliJ there were no issues. However, when the **.Jar** was ran the error message above was thrown.

I could not find a direct action item to take with the Guava issue defined by @Laurent Perez above so I did the following which resolved the issue with my **.Jar** file running:

- Removed **.Jar** IntelliJ configurations and file from IntelliJ. Then re-added the **.Jar** following [*Step 3*](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-a-backend-app-as-an-android-engineer-49bd94b4c367) from this deploy guide.

Other actions to try if the above does not work:

- Rebuild project.
- Invalidate IntelliJ cache and restart.
- Restart computer.

Comment: Please don't make your answer dependent on an external link - copy the relevant parts, as the link can break at any time.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you're missing guava library from your dependency. Add it using following in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>24.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Another reason could be there are multiple versions of google guava/collection library, you can't have both as mentioned by @sabbir in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084852/10512108), you ought to remove one of them.

Lastly it could be that some other dependency is dependent on the previous version of google guava/collections. Go to Dependency Hierarchy and search for google and see what all dependencies are dependent on the previous versions. In my case it was by version-maven-plugin, version 2.7

Here version-maven-plugin, version 2.7 uses google collections 1.0, and I require guava 24.0 Both can't work simuntaneously.
[image]

I excluded it in my pom.xml like this and then added a new dependency of guava

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>24.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

Resultant: Now google-collections is gone.
[image]