# Cloud Translate API Java client - problems using source, target lang

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-translate

I have an issue here that I'm hoping to resolve. First, when I call the cloud Translate service with source and target languages, I encounter the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.optionMap(TranslateImpl.java:131)
at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.access$000(TranslateImpl.java:40)
at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl$4.call(TranslateImpl.java:113)
at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl$4.call(TranslateImpl.java:110)
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
protected Translate getTranslationServiceClient() throws IOException {
        if (translationServiceClient == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (translationServiceClient == null) {

                    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(getCredentialFilePath()))) {

                        final GoogleCredentials myCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(is);
                        translationServiceClient = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(myCredentials).build().getService();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        throw new NuxeoException(ioe);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return translationServiceClient;
    }

    public TranslationResponse translateText(String text, String sourceLanguage, String targetLanguage) throws IOException {

        Translation response = translationService.translate(text, TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"), TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("es"));
        //System.out.println(response.getTranslatedText());
        GoogleTranslationResponse gtr = new GoogleTranslationResponse(response);

        return gtr;
    }
```

The error points to the Cloud's TranslateImpl class optionMap method and spills the NoSuchMethodError on the checkArgument. Am I Passing the TranslateOption's incorrectly??:

```
private Map<TranslateRpc.Option, ?> optionMap(Option... options) {
Map<TranslateRpc.Option, Object> optionMap = Maps.newEnumMap(TranslateRpc.Option.class);
for (Option option : options) {
  Object prev = optionMap.put(option.getRpcOption(), option.getValue());
  checkArgument(prev == null, "Duplicate option %s", option);
}
return optionMap;
```

}

In an effort to get any kind of response from the API, I've tried calling the service without passing any options or just the targetLanguage. Without any options, I don't have any errors and my texted is translated into english, as expected. If I just add TranslateOption.targetLanguage("es"), I still get the NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Please refer the below solution.. I have also faced similar issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247193/nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkargumentzljava-lan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same error.  The problem was an ancient version of Google Guava being brought in by some other dependency.  I found this by running `mvn dependency:tree`.  I had to exclude the ancient version of Guava like this

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```