# Spark submit through oozie work flow throws NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(object,object,object)

Tags: java, apache-spark, guava, oozie

I am having a oozie workflow where I am calling my spark action, there is an extra jar in the same folder lets say xyz.jar and my spark jar name is abc.jar. whenever I delete xyz.jar from that folder my abc.jar getting submitted properly, but once I add that jar in same folder it fails by giving below exception.
I can not remove xyz.jar as further actions are dependent on xyz.
in xyz.jar we have guava-27.1-jre.jar.
Spark-OPTS is not require if I am removing xyz.jar.. this is what extra I did to force to use guava 16.0.1.jar

action :

```
<action name="data_load">
            <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
                    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                    <master>yarn</master>
                    <mode>cluster</mode>
                    <name>Movement</name>
                    <class>com.package.Job</class>
                    <jar>path/lib/abc.jar
                    </jar>
                    <spark-opts>--jars path/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar --driver-class-path path/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=path/lib/guava-16.0.1.jar --conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true</spark-opts>       
            </spark>
            <ok to="notifyJobSuccess" />
            <error to="notifyJobFailure" />
```

error:

```
2020-06-18 16:06:13,481 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
            at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral.getParameterTypes(TypeLiteral.java:269)
            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forMember(InjectionPoint.java:113)
            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.<init>(InjectionPoint.java:72)
            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forMethod(InjectionPoint.java:316)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:293)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:135)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:105)
            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:347)
            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:356)
            at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:103)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:50)
            at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:61)
            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:347)
            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:104)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:105)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.build(WebApps.java:280)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:303)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.client.MRClientService.serviceStart(MRClientService.java:144)
            at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceStart(MRAppMaster.java:1148)
            at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$5.run(MRAppMaster.java:1553)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1549)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1482)
    2020-06-18 16:06:13,484 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45247710/7857701 it says to use version > 20.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, classpath management is hard when multiple big projects like Oozie and Spark are in play. Have you tried [shading your use of guava](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html)?