# How can I fix the 'NoSuchMethodError' exception when launching Hive via cmd?

Tags: hadoop, hive, data-science, bigdata

I'm trying to launch Hive from the command-line but it is giving me this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247193/nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-preconditions-checkargumentzljava-lan)